# How to draw a route between two markers points on Google Maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines doc says by making the `".geodesic(true)"` option, it will follow the curvature of the earth. But it just shows a straight line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +
   currentLatitude+","+currentLongitude+"&daddr="+fixedLatitude+","+fixedLongitude;
   Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse(uri)); intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"); startActivity(intent);
```

this might be  help you

Comment: this code sends to the googlemap direction. but i am passing the longitude latitudes by using a markers points run time . that latlngs are passed in your given code is not giving the route. i want to draw a route path between marker points.